# How can there be two stock tickers for one company?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

I was doing some research and came across two stock tickers with the same name eseentially, and the tickers are MDCN and MDCND. I'm not sure what each of these means and how this works within the financial realm? Also, which should I track, or should I examine both?

Comment: I cannot find any site that accepts the ticker "MDCND" as being valid (including Bloomberg). Where did you find that? I suspect that it is for either a preference stock class or ex/cum dividend.

Comment: Berkshire Hathaway would be another company that has different classes of stock that could be another way to view the title question. Look at the prices of BRK.A and BRK.B.

Comment: You can see it here http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=MDCND&ql=1 . I'm curious as to how this works?

Comment: You get what you pay for!  Basically Yahoo have screwed up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "D" suffix is designated for stocks that are going through a corporate reorganization and is typically applied for those stocks that is about to or just has undergone a reverse split.

It typically lasts about 20 trading days (almost a calendar month).

In the case of MDCN (Medican Enterprises) is traded as MDCND for the period 20150418 until 20150514.  On 20150515 it reverted back to MDCN.  It had a 10:1 reverse split with exdate 20150420.

Regarding multiple tickers - a ticker is just a point-in-time identifier.  This company has had many tickers across its lifetime: TCXC TCXB TCXBD MDCN MDCND and possible XCAL and XCALE.

The 5th letter suffix is detailed here:
http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/nasdaqfifthcharactersuffixlist.pdf

Comment: Thanks. So you say shares were traded under MDCND for about a month then reverted back. On yahoo finance it looks like it's still activehttp://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=MDCND&ql=1 ? Also, can you provide a source for extensions on stock tickers and their meaning? Two others I'm examining are MCPIE and OGRMF.

Comment: MCPI was MCPIE from 20150418 until 20150515 and reverted back to MCPI on 20150516.  E = Delinquent.  F = Foreign Stock.  OGRMF is a Canadian company.